# Dart - processing RxCommand result before send it to RxLoader

Tags: flutter, dart, reactive-programming, rxdart

I'm writing a Flutter app and I decided to use `RxDart` to pass my data and events along the managers, services and UI.
Basically I have a service which fetches data from a web service and returns it. Let's assume it returns a `List` of a model called `ExploreEntity`.

```
class ExploreMockService extends ExploreServiceStruct {
  final String response = /** a sample json **/;
  @override
  Future<List<ExploreEntity>> loadExploreData(PaginationInput input) async {
    await Future.delayed(new Duration(seconds: 2));
    return List<ExploreEntity>.from(jsonDecode(response));
  }
}
```

Now in my manager class I call the `loadExploreData` method inside a `RxCommand`.

```
class ExploreManagerImplementation extends ExploreManager {
  @override
  RxCommand<void, List<ExploreEntity>> loadExploreDataCommand;

  ExploreManagerImplementation() {
    loadExploreDataCommand = RxCommand.createAsync<PaginationInput, List<ExploreEntity>>((input) =>
        sl //Forget about this part
            .get<ExploreServiceStruct>() //and this part if you couldn't understand it
            .loadExploreData(input));
  }


}
```

And finally I get the result by a `RxLoader` and pass it to a `GridView` if data was fetched successfully.

```
class ExplorePageState extends State<ExplorePage>{
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Explore"),
        ),
        body: Column(children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
            child: RxLoader<List<ExploreEntity>>(
                commandResults:
                sl.get<ExploreManager>().loadExploreDataCommand.results,
                dataBuilder: (context, data) => ExploreGridView(data),
                placeHolderBuilder: (context) => Center(
                  child: Center(
                    child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                  ),
                ),
                errorBuilder: (context, error) => Center(
                  child: Text("Error"),
                )),
          )
        ]));
  }
}
```

It works like a charm but when I wanted to load the data of the next page from web service and append it to the list, I couldn't find a solution to store the content of previous pages and just append the new page's contents to them, since data is passed along the `RxCommand` and `RxLoader` automatically.

When `loadExploreData` sends the reponse to the manager, I need to firstly append the result to a list, and then send that list as the result to `RxLoader`. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm that's a good question if this can be done just using Rx. What I would do is keeping a list of the received items in the manager. So when triggering the command to get the next page the command would first add the new data to the list and then push the whole list to the UI.
I"m curious if there is another solution.

My described approach in a rough code sample

```
class ExploreManagerImplementation extends ExploreManager {
  List<ExploreEntity>> receivedData = <ExploreEntity>[];

  @override
  RxCommand<void, List<ExploreEntity>> loadExploreDataCommand;

  ExploreManagerImplementation() {
    loadExploreDataCommand = RxCommand.createAsync<PaginationInput, List<ExploreEntity>>((input) 
      async {
         var newData = await sl //Forget about this part
         .get<ExploreServiceStruct>() //and this part if you couldn't understand it
            .loadExploreData(input);
     receivedData.addAll(newData);
     return receivedData;
     };
  }


}
```

Comment: thank you sir... I was thinking of that, But I couldn't implement it... Could you please provide me some code? Also In this way, I have to give up on RxLoader?

Comment: Thank you sir, your answer helped me and works as I needed... I noticed an issue that is not related to question but I'm gonna ask you anyway to see if you know what's wrong... I have removed the `placeHolderBuilder` from `RxLoader` because I'm not gonna hide list every time that I want to load new data to list and show a `CircularProgressIndicator`. But it is kept showing anyway, even I replaced it with a `Text` widget, but I get `CircularProgressIndicator` everytime I run `loadExploreDataCommand`. Maybe it's a bug of `RxLoader`?

Comment: Can you raise an issue about this on the rx_command repository? Please add the source code there too.